# How to use replace in SQL Server for calculation

Tags: sql-server

My query is like this:

```
Select 
    Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Formula, 'No1', NoRepetations), 'No2', NoCounts), 'L', L), 'W', WB), 'DH', HD) As FormulaValue,  
    * from MeasurementDetailMasterSKP
```

My output looks like First Table From Picture:

You can see my `FormulaValue` column needs a mathemetical calculation. And it should look like 2nd Table Of Column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It7Qz.png)

Basically I have a Column Name Formula. In formula Column I am storing actual formula for calculation. And, I am using Replace, To replace all the variables of formula with the actual value. It is getting replaced successfully. but not doing calculation for me. Just showing like, formula as assigned value. But in my case, i want calculated answer from sql server only.

Please help me in this,

Comment: Give data sample and a sample result..

Comment: Could you elaborate on the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. As this is your first question, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for best practices on how to ask a question - good questions allow other members to quickly understand your problem which lets them focus on _solving_ it, instead of spending excessive time _understanding_ it. Pay attention to how to create an MCVE example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is EVAL() function.  But there is not (natively) such a function in MSSQL.

You can try this, but only to make some "experiments".

```
--DROP TABLE MDM_SKP;

CREATE TABLE MDM_SKP
(
ID int    ,
Formula varchar (100),
NoRepetations NUMERIC(6,2),
NoCounts NUMERIC(6,2),
L NUMERIC(8,4),
WB NUMERIC(8,4),
HD NUMERIC(8,4)
);
Insert Into MDM_SKP
Values(0, 'No1*No2*L*W*DH', 1,1, 1,1,1)
, (1, 'No1*No2*L*W*DH', 1,2, 4,2,3)
      ;

    DECLARE @sql_comm AS VARCHAR(MAX);    
    SET @sql_comm=''
    Select @sql_comm=@sql_comm + 'SELECT '+ CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' AS ID,'+ Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Formula, 'No1', NoRepetations), 'No2', NoCounts), 'L', L), 'W', WB), 'DH', HD) +' AS FV' + ' UNION ALL ' 
    from MDM_SKP       
    SET  @sql_comm=LEFT(@sql_comm, LEN(@sql_comm)-9)

    EXEC (@sql_comm)
```